# Kingfisher + RxSwift DownsamplingImageProcessor image failed

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, kingfisher

#### Issue Description

I have bigger images pulled from the server that I want to process in the app memory consumption to be smaller as the app consumes a lot o memory in order to show the images in its original form. I  am using Kingfihser and Rxswift, using the snippet below, in all my project. once I added the built-in processor DownsamplingImageProcessor, the images don't get shown until I scroll up or down.

When removing the processor the images get shown without any problem.

the error

> Kingfisher - Job failed: Processing image failed. Processor: DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: (0.0, 0.0), identifier: "com.onevcat.Kingfisher.DownsamplingImageProcessor((0.0, 0.0))"). Processing item: image(, {250, 250}).

Code

```
//Setup
   func setupKingfisher() {
        // Set maximum disk cache size for default cache. Default value is 0, which means no limit.
        ImageCache.default.diskStorage.config.sizeLimit = UInt(500 * 1024 * 1024) // 500 MB

        //cache.memoryStorage.config.totalCostLimit = 300 * 1024 * 1024

        // Set longest time duration of the cache being stored in disk. Default value is 1 week
        ImageCache.default.diskStorage.config.expiration = .days(7)

        // Set timeout duration for default image downloader. Default value is 15 sec.
        ImageDownloader.default.downloadTimeout = 10.0
    }
```

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIImageView {

    public var imageURL: Binder<URL?> {
        return self.imageURL(withPlaceholder: R.image.image_logo_cs_big())
    }

    public func imageURL(withPlaceholder placeholderImage: UIImage?) -> Binder<URL?> {

        return Binder(self.base, binding: { (imageView, url) in
            imageView.kf.setImage(
                with: url,
                placeholder: placeholderImage,
                options: [
                    .processor(DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: imageView.bounds.size)),
                    .cacheOriginalImage,
                    .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                    .transition(.fade(1)),
                ])
            {
                result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    print("Kingfisher - Task done for: \(value.source.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Kingfisher - Job failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Look like it's a kingfisher error. Try remove some options in your kingfisher.

Comment: so I changed the size to a static one and it works.
So I guess this one size: imageView.bounds.size returns nil or empty when first loaded